# Typecasting with as in Swift

Tags: swift, casting, nserror

I'm trying to understand of `as` typecasting.

Reading Type Casting chapter on Apple Documentation, I've two syntax for downcasting (as? and as! operators) but I didn't find anything about `as`.
So I thought that I should never have used this kink of operator but yesterday when I was typing code with `do-try-catch` statement, I met this one:

```
catch let error as NSError {
      print(error)
}
```

Initially, error was type conforms to the `Error protocol`.
Now using the `as NSError` casting, it has become an instance of a `NSError` class.

But my question is: What does as operator do?
It's not a downcasting sure.. Could it be used for "convert" object?

**EDIT** 
I don't think it's a duplicate. 
In my case, the error variable, is not a class and doesn't inherit from a super class so I have not a upcasting. It is not even a `pattern matching`.
I've already read both Swift Blog page and this thread on StackOverflow.

**EDIT 2**
From Swift Blog

> Swift 1.2 separates the notions of guaranteed conversion and forced
>   conversion into two distinct operators. Guaranteed conversion is still
>   performed with the as operator, but forced conversion now uses the as!
>   operator. The ! is meant to indicate that the conversion may fail.
>   This way, you know at a glance which conversions may cause the program
>   to crash.

The text above doesn't work for me because if I tried to use the `as!` operator instead of `as`, compiler complain me.

**EDIT 3**
Even in [Using Swift with Cocoa and Obj-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html) documentation they use the `let-as?` syntax for checking and casting to a protocol.
So, why in my case, I can't use it?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=23

Comment: Note that the last `as` is not an operator, but part of the `let`-`as` syntax.

Comment: The `as` operator here is used to bridge objective-c types and swift types. E.g. `Error` and `NSError`, `Double` and `NSNumber`, etc.

Comment: @Alistra but Error is a protocol and NSError is a class.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight But I didn't found a `let-as` syntax. I found it with down-casting operator ( let as?)

Comment: I've added two edit

Comment: Your code example definitely is a [`pattern`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/pattern), it's a [`value-binding-pattern`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/value-binding-pattern) containing [`as-pattern`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/as-pattern).

Comment: @ndPPPhz yes, and if I understand correctly, anything that is returned as the `Error` protocol in swift can be used in Objective-C and it gets converted to `NSError`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as suggested in the dasblinkenlight's comment, your code snippet is not using a *[type-casting-operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/type-casting-operator)*. Check the syntax of *[do-statement­](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/do-statement)* and you can find these:

> *catch-clause* → `catch­` *[pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/pattern)­opt ­[where-clause](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/where-clause)­opt ­[code-block­](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/code-block)*
>
> *pattern* → *[value-binding-pattern­](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/value-binding-pattern)*
>
> *value-binding-pattern* → `var` *[­pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/pattern)* |­ `let` *[­pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/pattern)*­
>
> *pattern* → *[type-casting-pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/type-casting-pattern)*­
>
> *type-casting-pattern* → *[is-pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/is-pattern)*­ | *[as-pattern­](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/as-pattern)*
>
> *as-pattern* → *[pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/pattern)* `­as` *[­type](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/type)*­

So, your **EDIT 2** has no meaning, there are no syntax accepting `as!` in *catch-clause*.

---

But this code (using *type-casting-operator*) works, so I try to explain how to use `as`-casting.

```
    enum MyError: Error {
        case bad
        //...
    }
    let error: Error = MyError.bad
    let nsError = error as NSError
```

As shown in the linked article in the EI Captain v2.0's comment, `as`-casting is used for **Guaranteed conversion**. I have collected some use cases of such conversions.

- Upcasting

  ```
  class Animal {}
  class Dog: Animal {}
  let d = Dog()
  d as Animal     // upcast succeeds
  ```

  As shown in the article, upcasting always succeeds, so you can use `as`.
- Specifying literal type

  ```
  let byte = 123 as UInt8
  let ch = "a" as UnicodeScalar
  ```

  In Swift, literals are *typeless*, so you can use `as` to specify the types of literals

  In case Swift can infer the type of the literal, you can omit such `as`-casting:

  ```
  let byte: UInt8 = 123
  let ch: UnicodeScalar = "a"
  ```
- Disambiguating overloaded methods

  ```
  class MyClass {
      func aMethod(_ arg: String) {
          print(arg)
      }
      func aMethod(_ arg: Int) {
          print("\"\(arg)\"")
      }
  }
  let obj = MyClass()
  let theFunc = obj.aMethod as (String)->Void
  theFunc("abc") //->abc
  ```
- Always-succeeds bridging

  ```
  let str: String = "a String"
  let nsStr = str as NSString

  let intArr: [Int] = [1,2,3]
  let nsArr = intArr as NSArray
  ```

  The example `let nsError = error as NSError` is included in this category, and you need to read [this article](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0112-nserror-bridging.md) carefully, to understand why this is an *always-succeeds bridging*.

---

For your **EDIT 3**.

You may need to distinguish these two syntaxes:

```
let a: Any = 1

//Using if-let -- Optional binding, `(a as? Int)` is an expression using type-casting-operator which generates an Optional result
if let intA = (a as? Int) {
    print("\(intA) is Int")
}

//Using if-case -- pattern matching, `(let intA as Int)` is a pattern using as-pattern
if case (let intA as Int) = a {
    print("\(intA) is Int")
}
```

As already noted, `catch` leads a *pattern*, and you cannot use `as?` in *pattern*.

Answer (score 0):

#### as

Use `as` for types that Apple has done some work to handle the conversion in the background. These are usually Foundation types that Apple bridged into Swift and want you to have a quick way to convert back and forth from their ObjC equivalents, for example:

```
String <-> NSString
URL    <-> NSURL
Array  <-> NSArray
Data   <-> NSData
```

These casts always succeed and Xcode will warn you if you use `as?` or `as!`. In your specific case, Apple has done some meddling in the background to make the `Error` protocol and `NSError` to be castable to/from each other.

#### as!

Use `as!` when you *know* the object is castable to another type. `as!` will crash your app if the object is not castable (for example, when `sender` is actually a `UITextField`)

```
let button = sender as! UIButton    // you are sure that the sender is always
                                    // a UIButton or your app will crash
```

#### as?

Use `as?` when you not sure if the object is castable to the other type. In practice, this should be your preferred method and you should optional binding to check for success. `as?` produces `nil` if the object is not castable:

```
// Exit the function if the sender is not a UIButton
guard let sender = sender as? UIButton else {
    return
}

// Only execute the block if the sender is UIButton
if let button = sender as? UIButton {
    // ...
}
```